# ConnectionLoss for /hbase + Connection reset by peer?

Tags: hbase, apache-zookeeper

I'm running a Hadoop MapReduce job on my local machine (pseudo-distributed) that reads from and writes into HBase. I'm intermittently getting an error which disrupts the job, even when the computer is left alone with no other significant processes running -- see log below. The output from a ZooKeeper Dump after the job has died looks like this, with the number of clients growing after a failed run:

```
HBase is rooted at /hbase
Master address: SS-WS-M102:60000
Region server holding ROOT: SS-WS-M102:60020
Region servers:
 SS-WS-M102:60020
Quorum Server Statistics:
 ss-ws-m102:2181
  Zookeeper version: 3.3.3-cdh3u0--1, built on 03/26/2011 00:20 GMT
  Clients:
   /192.168.40.120:58484[1]\(queued=0,recved=39199,sent=39203)
   /192.168.40.120:37129[1]\(queued=0,recved=162,sent=162)
   /192.168.40.120:58485[1]\(queued=0,recved=39282,sent=39316)
   /192.168.40.120:58488[1]\(queued=0,recved=39224,sent=39226)
   /192.168.40.120:58030[0]\(queued=0,recved=1,sent=0)
   /192.168.40.120:58486[1]\(queued=0,recved=39248,sent=39267)
```

My development team is currently using the CDH3U0 distribution, so HBase 0.90.1 -- is this an issue solved in a more recent release? Or should there be something I can do with the current setup? Should I just expect to restart ZK and kill off clients periodically? I'm open to any reasonable option that will allow my jobs to complete consistently.

```
2012-06-27 13:01:07,289 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server SS-WS-M102/192.168.40.120:2181
2012-06-27 13:01:07,289 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established to SS-WS-M102/192.168.40.120:2181, initiating session
2012-06-27 13:01:07,290 WARN org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session 0x0 for server SS-WS-M102/192.168.40.120:2181, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:21)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:202)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:169)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:243)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.doIO(ClientCnxn.java:858)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1130)
[lines above repeat 6 more times]
2012-06-27 13:01:17,890 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormat: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ZooKeeperConnectionException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ZooKeeperConnectionException: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getZooKeeperWatcher(HConnectionManager.java:991)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.setupZookeeperTrackers(HConnectionManager.java:302)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.<init>(HConnectionManager.java:293)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager.getConnection(HConnectionManager.java:156)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.<init>(HTable.java:167)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.<init>(HTable.java:145)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormat.setConf(TableInputFormat.java:91)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:62)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:117)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:605)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:322)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1115)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:262)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ZooKeeperConnectionException: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZooKeeperWatcher.<init>(ZooKeeperWatcher.java:147)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getZooKeeperWatcher(HConnectionManager.java:989)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:90)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:42)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.create(ZooKeeper.java:637)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKUtil.createAndFailSilent(ZKUtil.java:902)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZooKeeperWatcher.<init>(ZooKeeperWatcher.java:133)
    ... 16 more
```

Comment: I've seen connection loss when there is too much IO for the given machine. You might be biting off more than you can chew with hbase/zookeeper/hadoop M/R and other things on your machine. Do you have ganglia installed? It might show you how much processing you're using and if you're hitting an IO wall or thrashing.

Comment: One amendment to initial description: number of client connections did not permanently increase after job failure. According to the bug described on the HBase Jira, I may see this happen if the job completes successfully.

Comment: @Mike I wasn't really running any other processes of significant consequence at the same time, but it's a smart idea to keep tabs on system resources. Fortunately my machine seems to be beefy enough for the task at hand.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that I was hitting the low default limit of ZooKeeper (which I believe has been increased in more current releases). I had tried setting a higher limit in hbase-site.xml:

```
<property>
  <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.maxClientCnxns</name>
  <value>35</value>
</property>
```

But it didn't seem to work unless it was (also?) specified in zoo.cfg:

```
# can put this number much higher if desired
maxClientCnxns=35
```

The job can now run for hours and my ZK client list peaks at 12 entries.

Answer (score 1):

I've had issues similar to this in the past.  A lot of time with HBase/Hadoop you'll see error messages that don't point to the true issue you are having so you have to be creative with it.

This is what I've found and it may or may not apply to you:

Are you opening a lot of connections to a table and are you closing them when finished?  This can happen in a MR job if you are performing Scans/Gets in the Mapper or Reducer (which i don't think you want to do if it can be avoided).

Also, sometimes I get similar issues if my Mapper or Reducer is writing to the same Row a LOT.  Try to distribute your writes or minimize writes to reducethis problem.

It also would help if you went into detail about the nature of your MR job.  What does it do?  Do you have example code?

Comment: It's a job that uses OpenNLP's sentence splitter to generate a very large corpus of sentences from a modest corpus of documents. Each sentence gets its own row in the output table, and because the source documents are also in an HBase table, I just set up one Scan and set up the job with TableMapReduceUtil to use that Scan, my subclass of TableMapper (which generates Puts), and IdentityTableReducer. There was a Jira issue related to ZK connections being leaked when using TableOutputFormat, however, so I think that's what I am up against.

Answer (score 1):

Check for following parameters :

zookeeper session timeout( zookeeper.session.timeout) --> try to increase and check

zookeeper ticktime(tickTime)  -> increase and test

check for ulimit(linux command check for the user under which you hadoop/hbase is running) specificat

in the ulimit case you must have followin parameter somewhat to higher value.

open files  make this somewhat 32K or more

max user processes  make this as unlimited

after doing these changes verify most probably the error will be gone